# Is setcontext functions family in C a continuation?

Tags: c, continuations

How these two ([setcontext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext), [Continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)) concepts relates to each other? Do we create an instance of a continuation when using a `setcontext` technique?

Comment: I'd be tempted to answer that the difference is simply the same as the different philosophies between functional and procedural programming: `setcontext` will save local data because procedural programs have arbitrary explicit local data whereas continuations are said not to have data because functional programming is what to do, not how to do it. So the point is that you're partway through what to do — whatever the computer has accrued in doing it is probably stored but is not semantically relevant. But my degree of knowledge is insufficient for me to be confident of this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ucontext_t` object that you initialize via `getcontext()`, `makecontext()`, or `swapcontext()` preserves the stack and CPU state -- but not the heap -- in a way that can later be activated via `setcontext()` or `swapcontext()`.  This is similar to a continuation.

The subsystem seems not to have been designed with the idea of implementing continuations as such, however, but more as an improvement on `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()`.  In particular, contexts capture a signal mask, which is restored when the context is activated.  Each context also maintains a sense of a context to be resumed when the current context terminates.  In these senses, contexts may be considered to vary from pure continuations.

Note that `getcontext(`2`)`, `makecontext(`3`)`, and `swapcontext(`3`)` are now all deprecated by POSIX, leaving no direct, non-deprecated way for user code to obtain a valid context.  A three-arg signal handler still gets one as its third argument, but it's pretty useless because the effect of resuming that context is intentionally unspecified in recent versions of SuS / POSIX.